# How can I navigate past an unknown key name with a jackson JsonNode?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm parsing some output from an api, and I'd like to make the parsing logic as generic as possible. Many of the api calls return an object within a common wrapper. The responses look something like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": { 
        "object_type": {
            "object_id": { /* actual object data */ }
        }
    }
}
```

In this response, `object_type` can be one of a few different strings. I am writing a function to handle these responses that takes in a class reference for the inner object:

```java
private static ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

<T> APIResponse<T> parseResponse(String input, Class<T> clazz) {
    JsonNode node = MAPPER.readTree(input);
    boolean success = node.path("success").asBoolean(true);

    // This is what I'd like to be able to do but I can't seem to
    // find anything like it
    JsonNode objectNode = node.path("data").unwrap().firstValue();

    T object = MAPPER.treeToValue(objectNode, clazz);
    return APIResponse.of(success, object);
}
```

Is there a way to skip this string and id fields to get at the object? I know I can call .elements on the JsonNode and grab the first one, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

examining [`JsonNode` javdoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html), I came with the following snipet:

```
JsonNode data = node.path("data");
if (!data.isMissingNode()) {  // checks if data exists
    if (data.iterator().hasNext()) {  // checks if data is not empty
        // get first child ("unwrap")
        JsonNode firstNodeInsideData = data.iterator().next(); 
    }
}
```

you can use the same trick to get deeper inside the tree
note: this code sacrifices performance for brevity by calling iterator() twice. you can of course modify that to save the iterator into a variable first.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the only way to do it then.